# Macro/VBA Code to Copy Data From Text File Into Table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a macro in place that imports and parses data from a text file already. I need it now to look for a range of data that is always the same in every text file. The file has a lot of text in it but somewhere in the middle of the file it has the data below. I need it to copy and paste this data into the tables from the word "acct123456789" until "the customer service team". I am using MS Access. Maybe i would like to have a search box, have the user enter the account number and have it copy from the account number until the "the customer service team?

I have 10 fields which are named "f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10" in table "statement-find"

example:

```
Search Box: USER INPUT (ex. 123456789)
- Information found in the table called "statement-find".
- Macro/VBA copies information from acct 123456789 to the customer service 
team
- macro/vba pastes that range into a table called "statement"

Acct 123456789
Hello,

Thank you for your payment. Please view your receipt at www.test.com

Thank You,
The customer service team
```

Comment: Could you give a lot more information please.  A [MCVE] would definitely help. You need to paste it into the tables - what tables?  What fields are in the tables?  All that text in one field including line breaks, or split across more than one field?  Is that the exact text to go in each time, or is the text likely to go over 255 characters in which case a text field won't work?  When you say a text file I take it you mean a file with `txt` extension?  Most importantly - what have you tried so far and where is the exact, specific problem?

Comment: Hi Darren i added some more info on exactly table names, and what i am expecting the start and end to be

Comment: It appears that the "text file" has been computer generated from some other table.  Why bother parsing the text file? Why not read the prior table that has the data already in named columns?